# C++ - Using stringstream object to read strings and integers from a sentence in an external txt file

Tags: c++, ifstream, stringstream

I tried to retrieve the integers from a txt file and adding them up to get the total. I did this using `stringstream` class. The string of the text is:- `100 90 80 70 60`. The code to extract the integers and add them is as follows:-

```
#include<iostream>
#include<fstream>
#include<sstream>
using namespace std;
int main(void)
{
    ifstream inFile("C:\\computer_programs\\cpp_programs\\exp6.txt",ios::in);
    stringstream sstr;
    string from_file;
    int grade;
    int total = 0;
    getline(inFile,from_file);
    sstr<<from_file;
    while(sstr
    {
        sstr>>grade;
        cout<<grade<<endl;
        total+=grade;
    }
    cout<<total<<endl;
    inFile.close();
    return 0;
}
```

This code works fine. After this, I modify the string in the file as 'the grades you scored are 100 90 80 70 60`. Now, if try to run the above code, I get the output as:-

```
0
0
0
0
0
0
```

Can you please help me and tell me how to calculate the total in the latter case ? Also, here I know the number of integers in the files. What about the case when I don't know the number of grades in the file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because "the grades you scored are " is the head part of your stringstream.

You cannot get read an int from it. It'll just give you a 0

You may read to some string as "Entry" and parse the Entry by writing some functions.

Comment: is this code working? Its logic seems correct but the output is 0.

Comment: But the stream is still the same. If I am writing a string, I am actually overwriting the original contents of the stream and this means that the first number is printed three types-as a number, as a string. After this, the loop is terminated or goes in an infinite loop.

Comment: I tried his code on Linux-mint compile with g++ 4.8. It just show a 0 there. Not as him

Comment: That's because string is at the head of the file. Try to change the position of the string in the file and you will see what I am trying to say.

Comment: We can try running two streams. One for the numbers and another for the strings. This approach works. But I was hoping for something more "concise".

Comment: If all your integers are non-zero. It'll be very easy. Just do sstr>>gradestring; grade = atoi(gradstring.c_str()); if ( grade != 0 )...... You know that

Answer (score 0):

I'll be answering the second part of the question i.e. reading inputs without knowing the total number of inputs:-

```
#include<iostream>
#include<fstream>
#include<sstream>
using namespace std;
int main(void)
{
    ifstream inFile("C:\\computer_programs\\cpp_programs\\exp6.txt",ios::in);
    string data;
    int grades,total=0;
    getline(inFile,data);
    stringstream sstr;
    sstr<<data;
    while(true)
    {
        sstr>>grades;   
        if(!sstr)
            break;
        cout<<grades<<endl;
        total+=grades;
    }
    cout<<total<<endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: This post is not made in the form of an answer. Can you please edit this post clarifying how this might be the correct answer/solution?